# How to pass input value from multipart/form-data in jsp to servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, multipartform-data

I know that maybe it can be a duplicated question, i read similar post on internet, but i cannot send my input value from jsp to servlet.
I can upload file but i need to send an input value.
Servlet:

```
try {
                FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
                    InputStream in = item.openStream();


                        if (item.isFormField()) {
                            out.println("Got a form field: " + item.getFieldName());


                            } else {
                                String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                                String fileName = item.getName();
                                String contentType = item.getContentType();
                                String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileName);

                                out.println("--------------");
                                out.println("fileName = " + fileName);
                                out.println("Kind = " + fileNameWithOutExt);
                                out.println("field name = " + fieldName);
                                out.println("contentType = " + contentType);

                                String fileContents = null;
                                try {

                                    fileContents = IOUtils.toString(in);
                                    out.println("lenght: " + fileContents.length());

                                    String[] content = fileContents.split("\n");


                                    String[] property = content[0].split(",");

                                    out.println("lunghezza " + property.length);
                                    for (String propr : property) {
                                         out.println("prop: " + propr);
                                     }
                                    //out.println(Arrays.toString(property));
                                    //out.println(fileContents);
                                } finally {
                                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
                                            }

                                    }
                                            }
                } catch (SizeLimitExceededException e) {
                    out.println("You exceeded the maximu size ("
                            + e.getPermittedSize() + ") of the file ("
                            + e.getActualSize() + ")");
                                                    }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                throw new ServletException(ex);
                                }
                                                            }
```

And that's my jsp

```
    <form action="/upload_kind" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<input type="text" name="namespace" id="namespace">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

I read about a "item.getString()" method but it's in DiskFileItem class and not in FileItemStream, so i can see that "namespace" is sent, but i cannot see its value.
Thx and sorry for my bad english

Comment: What's your input value? If that's namespace , you should be able to get it via request.getParameter("namespace").

Comment: it's namespace but i'm not able to get it cause of "multipart/form-data". It returns null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Comment: I'll post some code later (I've done file upload using Apache commons and I'm sending additional attributes as well)

Answer (score 1):

Following the duplicated link, i was able to resolve my problem. I used this code:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
                String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldValue = item.getString();
                // ... (do your job here)
            } else {
                // Process form file field (input type="file").
                String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                InputStream fileContent = item.getInputStream();
                // ... (do your job here)
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
    }

    // ...
}
```